# Bioinformatics pipeline flow chart guidelines?

Tags: paper-submission, writing, graphics, formatting, bioinformatics

I am going to start work on the Materials and Methods for a paper I contributed to a lot in the bioinformatics processing part. I have seen [some papers](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Flowchart-of-the-main-steps-and-bioinformatics-tools-required-for-pathway-reconstruction_fig1_233751111) nowadays tend to first present the processing steps that they followed as a flow chart, to show the reader what happened generally before going into details in the written M&M section.

Are there any specific guidelines for creating this flowchart? Do you have any tips or advice from personal experience?

Comment: Welcome to Academia Stack Exchange! Maybe you can add a link to an example of those flow charts?

Comment: Welcome to Academia. Asking for lists such as guidelines are shopping questions, which are off topic for this site. Also, you're asking about the subject of research, which is also off topic of this site.

Comment: @RichardErickson What exactly is on topic then?

Comment: From the [help page](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): _If you have a question about...academic careers, requirements and expectations of students, postdocs, or professors, inner workings of research departments,
academic writing and publishing, studying and teaching at institutions of higher education (universities, colleges, …), ... then you're in the right place!_

Comment: @RichardErickson but this is asking about precisely that: "academic writing and publishing". About whether or not there are any guidelines about when and how one should present a computational pipeline as a flowchart. I'll grant you it's too broad, and probably opinion based, but off topic?

Comment: @terdon I disagree and think is is a domain specific writing question that might fit better on another SE site like the bioinformatics site. However, you're free to start a meta-question if you'd like others to chime in and think the question should be re-opened.

Comment: @RichardErickson fair enough, but as a bioinformatician and ex mod of the bioinformatics site, I don't see how it's specific to the field. I would say all questions about publishing papers would be better served here. But yes, meta is the place to discuss it.

Answer (score 0):

This sadly doesnt seem to be stated as a question proper for the site as noted in the comments. Perhaps you can rephrase it and add some examples.

From personal experience, UML is widely accepted for the symbols and flow of charts on various charts. There are software to so it easily like DIA (openware), flowchart (online) or Microsoft Visio. But there are plenty of sowftwares to do it. What you must abide to, however, is to be consistent.